# What does function return when "function times zero" in functional programming?

Tags: sml

I am stuck with this SML assignment. I am trying to create a compound function (fun compound n f). It's supposed to apply the function f on itself for n times for example, compound 3 f will equal to f(f(f(x))). I got it to work except for case where n is zero. I asked the professor but he won't tell me a direct answer. He tried to give me an hint that "what's function times zero?" I still can't figure that out either. Can stackoverflow figure it out?

Thanks.

My code:

```
fun compound n f =
    if n < 2 then
        if n = 0 then fn x => f x else fn x => f x
    else fn x => f(compound (n-1) f(x));
```

example:

```
val fnc = fn x => x + 1; (* example function to be used *)
compound 5 fnc(10); (* will return 15 which is correct*)
compound 0 fnc(10); (* returns 11, should be 10 *)
```

Answer:

```
fun compound n f =
    if n < 2 then
        if n = 0 then fn x => x else fn x => f x
    else fn x => f(compound (n-1) f(x));
```

Comment: `if n = 0 then fn x => f x else fn x => f x` seems like a typo; the two branches are the same (both are `fn x => f x`).

Comment: I left that like that so SML don't throw ugly errors at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you the final answer because I don't like to upset teachers ;) However, I'll try a derivation that I believe you'll find easy to complete.

Let's start from a very simple case. Let's "reimplement" function application, i.e., let's write a function that takes a function and an argument and apply the first param to the second one:

```
fun apply f a = f a
```

Let's use a contrived function, that increments integers, for testing:

```
- fun inc n = n + 1;
val inc = fn : int -> int

- inc 1;
val it = 2 : int

- apply inc 1;
val it = 2 : int
```

Now, let's write `apply2`, a function which takes a function and an argument and applies the param function two times to the argument:

```
fun apply2 f a = f (f a)
```

Let's test it with `inc`:

```
- apply2 inc 1;
val it = 3 : int
```

Seems to be working. As you might expect, we'd now implement `apply3`, `apply4` and so on. Let's see some of them at once:

```
fun apply f a = f a
fun apply2 f a = f (f a)
fun apply3 f a = f (f (f a))
fun apply4 f a = f (f (f (f a)))
```

It looks like we can rewrite later ones in terms of the earlier ones:

```
fun apply2 f a = f (apply f a)
fun apply3 f a = f (apply2 f a)
fun apply4 f a = f (apply3 f a)
```

We can even rewrite `apply`:

```
fun apply f a = f (apply0 f a)
```

Remember the previous definition of `apply`, they're equivalent:

```
fun apply f a = f a
```

So, what should `apply0` be?

```
fun apply0 f a = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the base case for this algorithm? i.e. at what value of `n` does the recursion terminate? When it terminated what do you return? Think about what you would want to return if `f` is not applied to `x`. In the context of your example, if `fnc` is applied to `10` zero times, what should be returned?

```
fun compound n f =
  (* If n equals the termination value, then return the base case*)
  if n = ?
  else fn x => f(compound (n-1) f(x));
```

There is a pattern here that exists in the base case for recursive algorithms. For example, what is the sum of a list with no elements? Or, what is the length of a list with no elements?